# How to attach an object in J3d core, J3d util

Tags: java

I have got a dynamically moving 3d object, say a cube. I intend to attach another object, say a sphere, on one side of this cube.

What I want is that as this cube (primary object) moves, the secondary object should move along with it, remaining totally attached/glued to it.

I am wondering if you could help.

Thank you

Comment: Please show the code what you have tried. Please read it before posting a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually it's simple, but given the few information in the question, the answer may sound vague: You have to attach them to the same transform group.

Some pseudocode with overly suggestive variable names here:

```
// The transform group that moves the cube
TransformGroup tgThatMovesTheCube = new TransformGroup();
tgThatMovesTheCube .addChild(new ColorCube(0.4));

// The transform group that "attaches" the sphere to the cube:
TransformGroup tgThatAttachesTheSphere = new TransformGroup();
tgThatAttachesTheSphere.addChild(new Sphere(...));

// The transform of this transform group: It is a transform
// that moves the sphere (from its original position) to 
// one side of the cube (at its original position)
Transform3D attachingTransform = new Transform3D();
attachingTransform.setTranslation(new Vector3f(1,0,0)); 
tgThatAttachesTheSphere.setTransform(attachingTransform);

// Attach the transformed (!) sphere to the same TG as the cube:
tgThatMovesTheCube.addChild(tgThatAttachesTheSphere);
```

Now, changing the transform of the `tgThatMovesTheCube` will cause the cube **and** the sphere to move in the same way.

The *relative* placement of the sphere and the cube is only determined by the `tgThatAttachesTheSphere`, and if you do not change its transform, it will behave as if the sphere was "stuck" on the cube.